# How to reference a customized list item

Tags: enumerate

How can I achieve the following result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} [label=\bfseries Definition No \arabic*:]

    \item \label{df1} Bla bla bla bla 
    \item \label{df2} bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
When I refer to the definition using \textbackslash ref\{df1\}, it displays\ref{df1} while I need to write it like as per "definition 1"
\end{document}
```

[image]
Can I get only the number of the list item in above case?

Comment: Your setup places most of the label far into the left-hand margin. Is this the desired look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the `enumitem` package, it's probably best to create a custom enumerate-like list (called "dflist" in the example below) and to employ the capabilities of the `cleveref` package to generate cross-references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newlist{dflist}{enumerate}{1} % create a custom enumerate-like list
\setlist[dflist]{ref=\arabic*,
                 label=\bfseries Definition No \arabic*:,
                 leftmargin=*}
\crefname{dflisti}{definition}{definitions}
\Crefname{dflisti}{Definition}{Definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{dflist}
    \item \label{df1} \lipsum*[1]
    \item \label{df2} \lipsum*[2]
\end{dflist}

When I refer to the definition using \verb+\ref{df1}+ and 
\verb+\cref{df1}+, \LaTeX{} displays~\ref{df1} and \cref{df1}, 
which is exactly what I need.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: A somewhat simpler solution would consist of simply adding the option `ref=definition \arabic*` to the setup of the enumerated list. That way, `\ref{df1}` would produce "definition 1". However, you'd have no flexibility in the format of the cross-reference, making it rather awkward to try to cross-reference both definitions simultaneously. That's why I suggest using the macros of the `cleveref` package.